# How does one get screen options from within a component in react navigation v5?

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I dynamically set the "headerShown" screen option but I can't sort out how to read the options from within a functional component

```
<Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: showHeader
}}>
```

Ive tried the navigation, route and state objects from within the component using useNavigation, useRoute and useNavigationState respectively and none seem to have a way to get the screen option values.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I couldn't find a way to do this without hacking our own solution to it.

Answer (score -2):

if your component is a screen, you can access the options of screen by doing this

```
function MyComponent({scene}) {
    console.log(scene.descriptor.options);
}
```